# Session laravel 5.3 not working over LAN

Tags: laravel, session, lan

currently using :

1. laravel 5.3
2. session driver already tried memcached,redis

my session data each refresh page it's always gone..

when i try using php artisan serve, it's normal not gone at all.. but when accessing from LAN.. it's look like no even stored at all..

i try using virtual host on my fedora but it's normal..

just because of accessing from LAN why my session can't stored at all?

is somebody experience something like this?

just scare if i up this app.. and this problem show up..

here's part of my login controler that stored email and token

> $req->session()->put('USER_TOKEN',$data->token);
>   $req->session()->put('USER_EMAIL',$result->param["email"]);

for get the session value in my home controoler

> $req->session()->get('USER_TOKEN');
>   $req->session()->get('USER_EMAIL');

best regards,

Comment: How are you accessing it?

Comment: using 192.168.1.11/blog/public

Comment: `php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.11 --port=1234`

Access it like `192.168.1.11:1234`

Comment: @RajenderJoshi i tried your solution but it's still not stored session..

Comment: may be some code can help from your login controller !!! hw you are storing your session.

Comment: @Bugfixer sure, for stored :                 $req->session()->put(Config::get(TOKEN'), $data->token);                $req->session()->put(Config::get('USER_EMAIL'),$result->param["email"]);